# JavaのデバックログにCQL文を出したい

Tags: java, cassandra

JavaからCassandraにCRUD処理を行う際、どういうCQL文を生成して実行しているのか知りたいです。
デバックログとかに出てくれたら最高なのですがどなたか確認方法わかりますか。
ちなみにDBのライブラリはScalarDBを使っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandraの公式ドキュメントを見ると、バージョン4.0からすべてのクエリーをログに記録する機能をサポートしたと書かれてありますね。このページを参考に、設定してみてはいかがでしょうか？

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/new/fqllogging.html